# Is DataGrid an alternative for UWP?

Tags: data-binding, uwp

I'm developing a UWP app that is supposed to be used on PC and Tablets and in a lite version later on mobiles.

On PCs I want to provide data in two columns, on mobile I intend to hide one of them (or I'll create a different page), depending to the user's actions.

Functionalities I need are; databinding to a `List<T>`(or anything equal), to filter, sort(not important) and select items, like I did before with the Datagrid.

Values of the selected item should be shown to be edited in two textboxes, so I need something like the `selectedItem` property. Also the content is not static since I need to be able to add and delete items.

Is there anything that I can use for this?

I already had in my mind to use two list views, but I guess scrolling will not work properly.

```
public class Items
{
   public Int32 id;
   public String name;
   public String name2;
}

List<Items> Test = new List<Items>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I need are databinding to a List(or anything equal), to filter, sort(not important) and select items**

As far as I know, there’s no build-in DataGrid control in UWP. If you want to show your data as a table, you would have to do it by yourself. For example, you could use ListView and GridView, custom its ItemTemplate to make it look like a DataGrid. It’s a good start with “[Guidelines for list view and grid view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465465.aspx)”.

If you don’t want to do it by yourself, you could think about using some opensource library. You could use Bing to search with this keyword: [UWP DataGrid Control](http://www.bing.com/search?q=UWP%20DataGrid%20Control%20github&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=uwp%20datagrid%20control%20github&sc=0-21&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=62A2D565AC684F078E675BB18A0FA2C2)

**Also the content is not static since I need to be able to add and delete items.**

In UWP, you could use “[ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)” instead of “List”, because it has implemented the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209899) interface, when you add and delete items, it would update UI automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use GridView, it's default behavior is fit as much items in row as possible, so if your 'column' would be 500px wide, just create 1000-1400px wide GridView and you'll have two columns and X rows.

As gridview's ItemsSource use ObservableColletion instead of List, it's able to react on added or deleted items automatically.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a `DataGrid` control that is part of the Windows Community Toolkit, [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid)