# how can i add dataGrid in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I am new in UWP and don't have enough idea how things work. I want to know how can I use `DataGrid` like in WPF in UWP. and how can I display whole database in that `DataGrid`

Comment: This answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962841/is-datagrid-an-alternative-for-uwp

Comment: The Telerik UWP controls were open sourced. They have a grid control in the controls set I think you can use. http://www.telerik.com/blogs/telerik-ui-for-uwp-now-open-source

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is DataGrid an alternative for UWP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962841/is-datagrid-an-alternative-for-uwp)

Comment: Another similar case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542792/how-to-customize-the-datagrid-in-uwp-apps/43578988#43578988

Answer (score 2):

use Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid
Res: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/datagrid

Exp:https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit//tree/harinikmsft/datagrid/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid

```
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"

 <Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="CVSposts" />
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>

    <controls:DataGrid x:Name="DataGridTTT" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  x:DefaultBindMode="TwoWay" Grid.Row="1" >
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="PostId"   Binding="{Binding PostId}" />
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Title"  Binding="{Binding Title}" />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Content1"  Binding="{Binding Content1}" />
            <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Tag="Col">
                    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate  >
                            <Grid Name="Grid1" Tag="{Binding BlogId, Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                <ComboBox  x:Name="ComboBoxTTT"     
                            SelectedValue="{Binding BlogId, Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                SelectedValuePath="BlogId"   DisplayMemberPath="Url"   ItemsSource="{Binding Blogss}"
                                />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        </controls:DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome on StackOverflow! Please consider including examples into your answer instead of simply linking to the documentation.